# Selenium unable to find web element

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, automated-tests

wanted to find the `webelement` through `xpath` hence used the following piece of code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="requestapp-37112114"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input"));
```

Note that my element doesn't have `id` or `classname`

it is throwing me error

```
in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="requestapp-37112114"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
```

any help would be much appreciated

My element:-

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML code. there can be lot of scenarios why it is throwing `NoSuchElementException`. Also check for iframe

Comment: <input type="password" class="v-textfield v-widget is-empty v-textfield-is-empty v-has-width" tabindex="203" maxlength="256" style="width: 200px;">

Comment: `//input[@type='password' and @class='v-textfield v-widget is-empty v-textfield-is-empty v-has-width']` is this unique in HTMLDOM?

Comment: no , there are two more fields using the same highlighted code in your abov comment

Comment: Can you share HTML for both of them?

Comment: Only tabindex is 204 and 205 for the rest two else all same

Comment: @VarunGole Check if value within @id="requestapp-37112114" changing on every refresh or new session, if so, then you need to handle this locator dynamically or in different way.

Comment: I found out why it's happening. From Home page , i click to change password option to navigate to Change Password and then when i say driver.getTitle() , it displays home , which is not expected as it should display Change Password

Comment: Ok so my change password page is using hashbang in url hence it's not redirecting??

Comment: Problem resolved , added implicitly wait and now working